# Why can't I add variable covariance noise to this 2D kalman filter?

Tags: matlab, filters, noise, kalman-filters

The goal is to include variable measurement noise to my kalman filter.
To begin with I kept the noise covariance matrix as follows:
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

This gave good results, the Kalman filter did a good job following the input data.

Next I tried to calculate the measurement noise covariance myself:
https://pastebin.com/7ETMC0Fy

Which gave such results:

[image]

Could someone tell me why when I try to calculate my measurement noise covariance matrix myself the result is unsatisfactory? Why doesn't the output of my Kalman filter follow the input data at all?

Comment: ...matplots figure functionality has an "export image" tool. Use that instead of posting screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
x = detrend([1, 5, 10, 15, 20,  1, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80]);
y = detrend([1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80]);
```

do:

```
x = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20,  1, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80];
y = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80];
dx = detrend(x);
dy = detrend(y);
```

and then:

```
  myMeanX = mean(dx);
  myMeanY = mean(dy);
  varianceX = 0;
  varianceY = 0;
  for i=1:length(dx)
       varianceX = varianceX + (myMeanX - dx(i))^2;
       varianceY = varianceY + (myMeanY - dy(i))^2;

  end
```

and

```
R(1,1) = varianceX/length(dx);
R(2,2) = varianceY/length(dy);
```

and I'm not sure why you're doing this:

```
%set everything to zero except diagonal
```

`P` should be as-calculated. No need to zero out entries.

---

The code you show must be wrong because:

```
[31.5202     0     0    0 
   0       0.0461  0    0
   0       0.0458  0    0
   0        0      0    0.0051]
```

shows you are setting off-diagonal entries in `R`.

---

Compare:

```
varianceX = varianceX + (myMeanX - x(i))^2;
```

with

```
varianceVx = varianceVx + (myMeanVx - VxMeas(i));
```

Notice anything²?

Also, it would be good if you could actually print out the values of your estimated `R` matrix.

² $\tiny \mbox{If you don't, please read it again.}$

Comment: Hi, thank your for your answer! Indeed I added a power of 2 (already tried that in the past), but the result still doesn't look as I expected it: http://imgur.com/a/uV9A0
Updated code: https://pastebin.com/R76tzrsp
This didn't solve the issue, any idea?

Comment: @wgujwhzi What are the values of `R` when you estimate?  Something is wrong as the Kalman gain should, in general, be going down not up. :-)

Comment: I really don't know what the issue is, I totally understand what you say and mean and why it is like that. But I just don't see what I am doing wrong. results of R: https://pastebin.com/GkSme6z8

Comment: @wgujwhzi Thanks. Those values are all over the shop, probably because the `x` and `y` values are linear. I'd suggest using `detrend` before finding the variance. Otherwise you're going to get very large variance values.

Comment: Im affraid this made it much worse... Or did I misunderstand you? http://imgur.com/a/F9go4 , value of R: https://pastebin.com/tXwtHh7v , code: https://pastebin.com/ane2NqFj

My measurements look kind of like nonsense now and so does the kalman output. (if that helps, I tried to implement the movement of a real object with those xy coordinates. It's an object moving from the left to the right but at some time the measurement of the position is incorrect. The error was represented by that "spike" in the linear line)

Comment: @wgujwhzi That code cannot be correct. See my updated answer. You are setting the wrong entries in `R`.

Comment: I know something is wrong with my code. But it has been 2 days so far that I have been trying to figure out what exactly is wrong! That's why I posted it here.

Comment: Oh, and don't apply `detrend` to `x` and `y`. Keep them as-is. Just use `detrend(x)` and `detrend(y)` when you calculate  the variances, not when you use `x` and `y` in the filtering.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when copying R!! This is correct: https://pastebin.com/nHHVRhfu

Comment: @wgujwhzi See updated update answer.

Comment: still doesn't really look like it should.

code: https://pastebin.com/9WD0b6m5
results: http://imgur.com/a/e6PMb
R: https://pastebin.com/7Sr3uj0m

Comment: just set Ts to 1. Now it looks much better actually. Could you maybe explain what the difference is between your implementation fro above and mine?

Comment: My main question and surprise! I actually expected a totally different kalman gain. I expected that ath the moment of the "spike", the kalman gain would drop very low indicating the measurement is probably totally incorrect while the rest of the time it would be a high value (near 1 for example).
See output: http://imgur.com/a/YXA3W
See code:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/24319467/

Comment: Especially for the x-coordinate you see the sudden spike but the kalman gain for the x-coordinate doesn't seem to be affected by it. I expected there to have a very low kalman gain at that point.

Comment: There's still something wrong. The Kalman gain shouldn't keep growing. That means there's a severe mismatch between your data and your model. See [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/10999/80) for example.

Comment: What do you suggest?